# Odd Python threading problem with QT

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

I have a module that multi-threads some code (using threading library) and on top of it, another module which implements GUI (using QT).

Now, everything seems to work fine, except that when I compile the code to a pyc file, and change the extension to pyw to get rid of the black CMD screen, the GUI works, multithreading inside the GUI module even works, BUT - the multithreading in the other module just doesnt work at all.

It seems like the thread never even starts, and I just end up waiting forever.

py file? works great, pyc file? works great, pyw file? threading inside smaller module doesnt work. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess its do with [Windows POpen Failures](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#why-doesn-t-os-popen-work-in-pythonwin-on-nt), you way want to look into using Qt's [QThreads](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html) instead.